# Solr not connecting to Drupal 8 site after changing root SSH login on Linode

Tags: solr, drupal-8

I recently changed the SSH login for the root admin account on my Drupal 8 website hosted on Linode. After this change, Solr lost connection to the site and is showing the following error message: "org.apache.solr.core.SolrCoreInitializationException: SolrCore 'drupal' is not available due to init failure: Could not load conf for core drupal: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/drupal/conf/solrconfig.xml". The solrconfig.xml file still exists at that directory, but it seems that Solr cannot access it.

Could the change in the root SSH login have affected Solr's ability to connect to the Drupal site? If so, where do I need to go to edit Solr's login configuration?

For additional context, the Solr dashboard currently shows no cores available. I attempted to add a core with 'name: drupal', 'instanceDir: drupal', 'dataDir: data', 'config: solrconfig.xml', and 'schema: schema.xml', however I'm getting this error message: "Error CREATEing SolrCore 'drupal': Unable to create core [drupal] Caused by: Solr no longer supports forceful unlocking via the 'unlockOnStartup' option. This is no longer necessary for the default lockType except in situations where it would be dangerous and should not be done. For other lockTypes and/or directoryFactory options it may also be dangerous and users must resolve problematic locks manually."

I also noticed that the dashboard is no longer prompting me for an admin login, which it used to do. I'm not sure why that would have changed.

Comment: i would suggest checking the permissions of the files and user to make sure the proper access is there.

Comment: Everything in the /opt/solr-5.4.1/server/solr/drupal/conf directory is marked -rw-r--r--, and the Owner/Group is "solr solr" (I'm on FileZilla)